# In my custom TypeScript declaration file, how can I include another declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have a few declarations in `src/types/*.d.ts` and in my `src/types/role.d.ts`, I have:

```
declare interface Role {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  openings: string;
  jobDescriptionUrl?: string;
  minCompRange: number | string;
  maxCompRange: number | string;
  location: string;
  postCovidLocation: string;
  urgency: ROLE_URGENCY;
  equity: ROLE_EQUITY;
  company?: Company;
  color: string;
  status: ROLE_STATUS;
  deletedAt?: Date;
  hiredAt?: Date;
  createdAt: Date;
  pausedAt?: Date;
  managerEmail?: string;
  managerName?: string;
  isExcRole?: boolean;
  recruiter?: Recruiter;
  offer?: File;
}
```

Somehow, it finds the `Recruiter` and `File`, but `Company`, which is declared in `src/types/company.d.ts`:

```
declare interface Company {
  companyName: string;
  companyUrl: string;
}
```

doesn't get found. I get an error:

```
src/types/role.d.ts:14:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Company'.

14  company?: Company;
              ~~~~~~~
```

In my `tsconfig.json`, I have:

```
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
    ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably [this article](https://medium.com/jspoint/typescript-type-declaration-files-4b29077c43) contains the answer to your question

Comment: It's a bit confusing. I read that people are moving away from `typeRoots` in favor of `include`'ing it all

Comment: Do you have [triple slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) declared anywhere in `role.d.ts`?

Comment: Nope - what does that mean?

Comment: Hm interesting. The reference directive (specifically `/// <reference types="...">`) lets you specify a dependency between different type files. I was thinking you might have missed the reference for `company.d.ts` but you say you don't have any references at all yet `Recruiter` and `File` work.

Comment: Can you share your entire `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: The compiler error shows line 14, but your code snippet doesn't match. Are there more lines at the top of the role.d.ts that you didn't share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `export interface Company` instead `declare interface Company` maybe solved!

Answer (score 4):

A special comment tells the typescript compiler to include another type-definition file

```js
/// <reference path="myCustomDecls.d.ts" />
```

This should be used only in other `.d.ts`-files

For the typescript compiler to actually acknowledge your `.d.ts`-files you'll also have to specify them in the `"compilerOptions" -> "typeroots"` like this

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": ["./types/"] // directory containing .d.ts-files
}
```

If you have multiple custom declaration files, I'd recommend creating an `index.d.ts` file, that includes all your custom `.d.ts`-files using the first mentioned "special comment"